# Work And Energy: Conceptual Potential Energy Doubt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy

Our teacher told us that objects store potential energy in them according the position of the object above the ground because of gravitational force.
Like we are holding a box up and it stores potential energy, and if we drop it, its potential energy gets converted to kinetic energy.

My doubt is,
If, we send a rocket outside the Earth, then after some point, the influence of Earth's gravitational field nearly comes to an end,
Then where does the potential energy of the rocket go if we stop providing it velocity (Like dropping the box)?

Comment: *after some point, the influence of Earth's gravitational field nearly comes to an end* Where is that point?

Comment: Objects don’t “store” or “possess” potential energy, which is a system property. If that’s what you’re teacher said, your teacher is wrong

Comment: I mean the Range of gravity is infinite but of course the strength decreases and also it is the weakest fundamental force in nature.

Comment: Actually Yeah my teacher said this, maybe to explain better as I am only in 9th grade.

Answer (score 1):

> Our teacher told us that objects store potential energy in them according the position of the object above the ground because of gravitational force.

Potential energy is a property of a system - in the case of a rocket, the system is the rocket *and* the Earth, and the potential energy is stored in the gravitational field between them. The further they are apart, the greater is the potential energy.

> Where does the potential energy of the rocket go ?

If the rocket and the Earth are the only objects on the universe and if the rocket reaches its furthest distance from Earth (its "apogee") then it starts to fall back towards the Earth. The potential energy that it has at its apogee is gradually converted into kinetic energy as it speeds up while it falls back towards Earth.

In real life, rocket trajectories are more complicated than this because of the existence of other objects besides the rocket and the Earth. For example, if the rocket gets close enough to the Moon then it will start to fall towards the Moon rather than back towards the Earth. In this case you have to think about the potential energy of the bigger system consisting of the rocket, the Earth *and* the Moon, which is a more complicated calculation.

Comment: Thanks for clearing!